# Вариант создании темы Мадженто 2?

Tags: magento, бэм

Всем привет! 
Разрабатываю новую тему для Magento 2, но возник вопрос "как лучше будет создать тему для Мадженто 2? ***Как правильней будет?***":

- использовать base шаблон и стили less-ом оформить, так сказать все возможности движка использовать, как (luma)

или

- сделать свои layuot, оформить по BEM методологии и т.д.

Из выше перечисленного возникают такие нюансы:
- В первом варианте меньше раздумий над структурой, но и ориентироваться по проекту сложнее.
- В другом варианте долго.

Как лучше будет для создания и для поддержки?
Расскажите про Ваш опыт создания темы?

Answer (score 1):

Хорошей практикой для написания темы считается наследование от Magento blank
Совету перед началом почитать офиц документацию.

Comment: Прочитано и даже больше старый проект сделаный по ВЕМ -  не легко. Темы просматривал и даже в этом опыте нет единства.Где же правда ?

Comment: Правда всегда посередине. Если хочешь хорошую совместимость с многими модулями комьюнити - лучше быть ближе к Маджентовской архитектуре во всех ее проявлениях. Если есть объективные причины не следовать ей... Ну ты понял

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: Очень настоятельно рекомендую использовать англоязычную версию этого ресурса. Комьюнити там на много обширнее и на много большее кол-во тем уже покрыто.

Comment: Спасибо но там только жители индии скринят доку от Мадженто.
А тут не в доке дело!

Comment: Позволю себе не согласиться.